# Removing a Line from a File without making a new file

Tags: c++, file, delete-file

I'm trying to remove a single line from a file without creating a new file. For example in the file before it is modified it would be:

```
This
is
a
file
```

and after it would be:

```
This
a
file
```

However, with the way I'm currently trying to do it what happens is

```
This
  a
file
```

I know I could do it by writing only the contents that I want into another file and then renaming that file and deleting the old one but I wanted to know if there is another way besides that.

I've tried using

```
if (string::npos != line.find(SPSID))
{
        iPos = (pos - line.size() - 2);

    stream.seekg(iPos);
    for (int i = (pos - line.size() - 2); i < pos; i++)
    {
        //Sets input position to the beginning of the current line and replaces it with NULL
        stream.put(0);
    }
    stream.seekp(iPos);
    pos = stream.tellp();
}
```

as well as replacing `stream.put(0);` with `stream.write(nullLine, iPos);`
but neither have worked.

```
int Delete(string fileName, string SPSID)
{
    //Variables
    string line;
    char input[MAX_CHAR];
    fstream stream;
    streamoff pos = 0;
    streamoff iPos = 0;

    //Opening and confirming opened
    stream.open(fileName);

    if (!stream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Did not open.\n" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Loops until the end of the file
    do
    {
        //Gets one line from the file and converts it to c++ string
        stream.getline(input, MAX_CHAR, '\n');
        line.assign(input);

        //Finds the current output position (which is the start of the next line)
        pos = stream.tellp();

        //Finds and checks if the SPSID is in the string. If it is then print to screen otherwise do nothing
        if (string::npos != line.find(SPSID))
        {
            iPos = (pos - line.size() - 2);

            stream.seekg(iPos);
            for (int i = (pos - line.size() - 2); i < pos; i++)
            {
                //Sets input position to the begining of the current line and replaces it with ""
                stream.put(0);
            }
            stream.seekp(iPos);
            pos = stream.tellp();
        }

    } while (stream.eof() == false);    //Checks that the end of the file has not been reached

    stream << "Test" << endl;

    //Resets the input and output positions to the begining of the stream
    stream.seekg(0, stream.beg);
    stream.seekp(0, stream.beg);

    //Closing and Confirming closed
    stream.close();

    if (stream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File did not close.\n" << endl;
        return -2;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I'm probably gonna have to make a new file and rename it but figured it was still worth asking if this is possible. :/

Comment: A file is basically an array.  You can't remove the middle element of an array without shifting everything after it forward.  You'd need to to the same thing to your file.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of that

Comment: After shifting everything in the file you may also have to convince the file to be shorter, something that's difficult to do without system-specific calls before C++17 and [the <filesystem> library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file). You nailed it. Making the new file is many times easier.